# Did the Mother break the Leg Lamp?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-christmas-story

In the movie [A Christmas Story](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085334/combined), the Mother (name unspecified) is suspect in the breaking of the Leg Lamp, because she never liked it. She seems believable when she says it was an accident and she doesn't know how it happened. However, while The Old Man (name unspecified) is trying to repair it, in the background she seems giddy that it is broken, and when his attention is returned to her, she immediately goes solemn and concerned. Is there evidence somewhere, even in the Jean Shepherd books and stories the movie is based on, that prove or disprove the Mother intentionally broke the lamp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's intentionally left ambiguous whether it was an accident or it was done on purpose.

Even in the short story that this incident is based on, ***My old man and the lascivious special award that heralded the birth of pop art***,  it's never stated outright if breaking the lamp was intentional.  Of course, in both the story and the movie the Mother is glad to see it go, and the Old Man accuses her of breaking it on purpose, but I don't think there's a definite answer.